# Issues with AngularJS $http-Service

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

The following code should fetch data from a MySQL Database with a `$http-service` but somehow the data, which the `service` provides doesn´t go to the controller/gets displayed wrong :/. If I start my application a empty or wrong table gets displayed at my page.

I provided some sampledata in the `getUsers()` function. The `PHP` code, which provides the data is working and this is a example of the `JSON` the `PHP` returns.

Maybe you guys can help me out to fix this up.

```js
var app = angular.module('DBapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, DatabaseService) {
 
  $scope.userData = DatabaseService.getUsers();
 
});

app.factory('DatabaseService', function($http) {
 
 var srv = {};
 
 //Service Implementation
 
 srv.getUsers = function() {
      return [{"user_id":"1","firstname":"Barrack","lastname":"Obama","email":"obama@web.de"},      {"user_id":"2","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Hanks","email":"tommy@web.de"},{"user_id":"6","firstname":"Felix","lastname":"Blume","email":"felix.b@selfmade.de"}];
 };
  
  
    //I provided some dummy-data in the getUsers-function as example output from the DB
  
 
 //Public API
 
 return {
  getUsers: function() {
   return srv.getUsers();
  }
  
 };
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DBapp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>DB Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div>
   
   <div>
     <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Overview Database</h1>
   </div>
        
   <table style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;" class="table table-hover"">
  
   <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Secondname</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>
  
   <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in userData">
       <td ng-bind="user.user_id"></td>
       <td ng-bind="user.firstname"></td>
             <td ng-bind="user.lastname"></td>
             <td ng-bind="user.email"></td>
             <td>
               <a ng-href="#/database/{{ user.user_id }}/edit"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>  Edit</button></a>
                                                                                                                      </td>
             <td>                                                                                                      <a ng-href="#/database/{{ user.user_id }}/delete"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Delete</button></a></td>
    
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 
 <add-user-form></add-user-form>
</div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src=lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js></script>
<script src=lib/angular/angular.js></script>
<script src=lib/angular-route/angular-route.js></script>

<script src=scripts/app.js></script>
<script src=scripts/services/db_service.js></script>
<script src=scripts/controllers/main_controller.js></script>
<script src=scripts/directive/addUser_form.js></script>
<script src=scripts/controllers/delete_controller.js></script>
<script src=scripts/controllers/edit_controller.js></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

As you can see above, it works with the dummy data. But if I change my service to the following code (with the actual `$http-request`) nothing works...

So the question is:

**How do I pass my data from the http request to the `$scope` in the `MainCtrl` ?**

```js
app.factory('DatabaseService', function($http) {
 
 var srv = {};
 
 //Service Implementation
 
 srv.getUsers = function() {
  $http.post("php/getData.php").success(function(data) {
   return data;
  });
 };
 
 //Public API
 
 return {
  getUsers: function() {
   return srv.getUsers();
  }
  
 };
 
});
```

`

Comment: I can't see where you are using the $http service........!

Comment: `getUsers` is not a function either, you declared it as an array

Comment: @Jorg fixed that up. As you can see in the first Snippet it works with the dummy data but not with the actual request

Comment: the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation is fairly clear. What have you tried so far?

Comment: several methods and variables to pass the returned data from the service in the controller scope value. but nothing worked

Comment: ok, just a moment I will add another answer

Answer (score 0):

It probably will work if you just return the array from your service like

```
return {
    getUsers: function() {
        return srv.getUsers;
    }
};
```

The function call you used is not possible.

Ok here comes part 2:
I had no chance to test it, but it should work.

```
app.factory('DatabaseService', function($http) {    
    var srv = {};

    //Service Implementation        
    $http.post("php/getData.php").success(function(data) {
            srv.users = data;
        });     

    //Public API        
    return {
        getUsers: function() {
            return srv.users;
        }
    };
});
```

Jorg is right, this part 2 was a hasty reaction, sorry. To return the promise is a possible solution, return $http.post("php/getDat.php"), and than in your controller add the success function

```js
DatabaseService.getUsers().success(function(data) {
  $scope.userData = data;
  });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It works with the array but I need to use a $http-request to get the data from the DB. I guess my functin from the second snippet is wrong somehow

Comment: use the success function of your $http call to pass the returned data to some object, like you did it directly with the array. And your service should return this object. Your function srv.getUsers invokes the $http call and registers the success callback but does not return anything.

Comment: Can you maybe provide some sample code for better understanding ?

Comment: That won't work. When using 'getUsers' , the request hasn't finished. You should return the promise or inject a callback

Comment: @jorg yeah, it doesnt work. But I´ll focus on your idea with the injected callback.